# semantic-ui javascript doesn't fire any actions

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, semantic-ui

I have followed the instructions in installing semantic from Semantic-ui.com. I successfully installed semantic in my project folder and build using gulp 
[image: running gulp build]

and I have my files in semantic/dist folder

[image: project folder]

I have the code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Semantic UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>Semantic ui</header>

      <div class="ui sidebar vertical left inverted menu">
        <a href="#" class="item">Monday</a>
        <a href="#" class="item">Tuesday</a>
        <a href="#" class="item">Wednesday</a>
        <a href="#" class="item">Thursday</a>
        <a href="#" class="item">Friday</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui basic icon top fixed menu">
          <a id="toggle" class="item">
              <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
              Menu
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="pusher">
          jflkjf f lekjflke fsdf s;lfks; kf;skvm ;sl;lfsdk g;ldkgl;ksd
      </div>

    <script>
      $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".ui.sidebar").toggle();
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I open index.html in my browser, I see the styling fine on my page but when I click on my menu I don't see anything firing. The dates don't show up. Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

just include jquery before semantic css

Comment: I did that but still have the problem. Is the way of including jquery wrong?